# Read byte from file and use value for if else statement to set boolean var. C#

Tags: c#

Very basic question. I read a byte from a file using `ByteReader`.
That byte is either one of two values (`0x42` or `0x4C`).
Now depending on that I want to set a bool value. By now I have this:

```
byte myByte = br.readByte();
bool myBoolean = true;

if(myByte == 0x4C) myBoolean = true;
else if(myByte == 0x42) myBoolean = false;
else return;
```

What I want to avoid is the two variables. I'd like to have just one bool value.
Like this

```
myBoolean = myByte == 0x4C ? true : false;
```

The thing is that this expression only checks for `0x4c` and not `0x42`

I can only call ReadByte() once because the read position is incremented.
Any ideas?

Comment: Note that it should be `ReadByte`, not `readByte`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to consider three different values (`0x42`, `0x4C` and anything else) with three different results (`myBoolean = true`, `myBoolean = false`, `return`). Hence, a single comparison will not suffice.

You can, however, use a switch statement to make the code a bit tidier and also avoid the `byte` variable:

```
bool myBoolean;
switch (br.ReadByte()) {
    case 0x4C:
        myBoolean = true;
        break;
    case 0x42:
        myBoolean = false;
        break;
    default:
        return;
}
```